# Something strange happen during using variable.length in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am now practicing some methods in javascript, like `shift(), unshift(), push(), pop()`, and I want to write a little function that will take 3 arguments, an array, a start point, an end point. Which is used to cut a part of array out, and then return both the new array and the cut part. Not a useful thing or a big deal, just want to practice javascript.

But I encountered a strange thing, which I don't know why.

Here is the strange part

```
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];

for(var i=0; i<a2.length; i++){
a1.unshift(a2.shift())
}
```

So I wrote this code, and the expected result should be

```
a1 = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a2 = []
```

However, when I run the code, this was what actually happened

```
a1 = [5,6,7,8,9]
a2 = [4,3,2,1]
```

It seems like the function was looped not enough time, so I tried to change the a2.length to a integer: 9

which make the code become

```
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];

for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
a1.unshift(a2.shift())
}
```

And that worked!

Then I change the approach to this

```
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
var aLength = a2.length;
for(var i=0; i<aLength; i++){
a1.unshift(a2.shift())
}
```

And this worked too!!!

Could anyone tell me why is that ???
And how can I improve the loop?

Thank you very much, really appreciate for your time.

Comment: Each iteration of for loop reduces the length of the a2 array by 1. so when it has looped thru 5, there is only 4 left, and index you are currently looping is 5. 5 < a2.length (4) at that point is false. Try doing the loop backwards `for (int i = a2.length - 1; i >=0; i--)`, or using while loop `while (a2.length > 0)`.

Comment: Oh... I am so silly... Thank you guys.

For the answer of flav, why the len inside for loop would not make a new copy of the a2.length every time when the loop is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this by using while loop

```
while (a2.length > 0)
{
    a1.unshift(a2.shift());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript Array: Shift() Method
>
> The shift() method is like the pop() method, only it works at the
>   beginning of the array. The shift() method pulls the first element off
>   of the given array and returns it. This alters the array on which the
>   method was called.

So when you do a a2.shift() it will actually modify (decrease the number of elements in the array) the array and thus the effect

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition is re-evaluated for each iteration, and `a2.length` is constantly changing.

If you want to use its *initial* value, cache it beforehand:

```
var n = a2.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   a1.unshift(a2.shift());
}
```